# Make an api call to fetch text

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spark-ar-studio

I am using [Spark AR](https://sparkar.facebook.com/ar-studio/) to create a simple effect that grabs text from an api and displays it.

Here is my code

```
const Scene = require('Scene');
const Diagnostics = require('Diagnostics');
const Patches = require('Patches');
const Textures = require('Textures');
const Materials = require('Materials');
const Networking = require('Networking');
const URL = 'https://gabby-airbus.glitch.me/random';


Networking.fetch(URL).then(function(result){
    if( (result.status >=200) && (result.status < 300)){ return result.json(); } 
    else { throw new Error('HTTP Status Code: ' + result.status); }
}).then(function(json){
    // show json data in console
    Diagnostics.log(json.item);

    // Asign json data to text object
    itemText.text = json.item;
}).catch(function(error){ 
    itemText = 'Failed to start'; 
    Diagnostics.log(result.status + error); 
});
```

I get the following error

```
Error:Cannot read property 'fetch' of undefined
   {
     "line": 12,
     "column": 17,
     "sourceURL": "script.js"
   }
```

I am not sure why i am getting undefined when https://gabby-airbus.glitch.me/random is clearly not undefined. it has a random json object.

I am following the solution suggested in this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56960033/how-to-fetch-a-json-with-sparkar-networking-module)

Comment: `require('Networking')` what is this?

Comment: https://sparkar.facebook.com/ar-studio/learn/documentation/reference/classes/networkingmodule/ @VivekDoshi I am using this Vivek.

Comment: "We’re temporarily disabling this capability while we work to improve performance and functionality. We'll reintroduce networking in the near future."

Comment: @VivekDoshi - oh crap that explains, so i guess is there any other way that i can fetch data from api?

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is not possible, the Networking capability is disabled for security reasons. There is a plan to have it back soon though.

https://sparkar.facebook.com/ar-studio/learn/reference/classes/networkingmodule