# How to make a GET request in SparkAR studio

Tags: javascript, spark-ar-studio

I am trying make a GET request in SparkAR studio. I am able to import the `https` module. However when the code runs I get the following error.

> Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: Cannot read property 'protocol' of undefined

I found a reference to the networking module in this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56960033/how-to-fetch-a-json-with-sparkar-networking-module) but the module is no longer supported. I get the following error.

> Some modules are not supported by the platforms selected for this project:
> Networking is not supported by Instagram, Facebook.
> You can review the platforms by selecting Project > Edit Properties...

My code is below. I am don't work with node.js usually hence there might be some obvious mistake which I might be doing.

```
const Scene = require('Scene');

export const Diagnostics = require('Diagnostics');

export const https = require('https');


(async function () {  // Enables async/await in JS [part 1]

    Diagnostics.log('Console message logged from the script.');
    Diagnostics.log(https);

    https.get('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?appid={openweathermap_apikey}&q=chicago', (res) => {
      Diagnostics.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
      Diagnostics.log('headers:', res.headers);

      res.on('data', (d) => {
        Diagnostics.log('Data:', d);
      });

    }).on('error', (e) => {
        Diagnostics.log('error:', e);
    });


})();
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot make HTTP requests from Spark AR Studio.